# My apply process in angularjs is broken. How can I fix it

Tags: debugging, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table which rows are rendered with ng-repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ...
```

My Controller watches the foreign key (fk) of the items. If I change "fk" the items are replaced with $http.

```
$scope.$watch('fk', function() {...}, true);
```

So far everything works fine - the items are changed if I change "fk".

NOW I add some "DOM-Stuff". I need to reorder the rows with Drag and Drop (jqueryui). The rows are reorder well.

If I now change "fk" the $http service loads the items and the "success method" seems to replace the items. But they are NOT rendered. I still see the old items. Why?

I have a button to apply changes. But it says always "Error: $apply already in progress"

```
<button ng-click="$apply()">$apply</button>
```

I think I can't expect a 100% answer. So you'll get points if you tell me how to debug effectively into the digest process, or how to trigger the $apply() process deadsure.

Comment: You say : "success method" **seems** to replace the items .. May be you should check this point first?

Comment: How have you implemented the Drag n Drop? Using a directive?

Comment: It seems DOM updation using jquery is creating the problem.